# Profiling an application on Windows with cabal/ghc

Tags: windows, haskell, profiling, cabal

I’ve been experiencing a nasty issue with profiling on Windows. But first, the context of setup:

- I created a shared sandbox in *~/dev/foo_shared*: `cabal sandbox init --sandbox=.`
- I created a sandbox in *~/dev/foo* using the shared sandbox above: `cabal sandbox init --sandbox=~/dev/foo_shared`
- I installed all the dependencies with profiling enabled: `cabal install --only-dependencies --enable-library-profiling --enable-executable-profiling`
- I configured the *foo* package so that it includes profiling RTS: `cabal configure --enable-profiling --enable-executable-profiling`
- I tried to build with `cabal build`

Everything builds up correctly, but doesn’t link. I then rebuilt with `cabal build -v3`, and this is the linker part (the most interesting part):

```
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lHSrts_debug_p
```

I googled that, and IIRC, it’s because I lack the profiling library for the GHC’s RTS. I never found it for Windows :( Last information, I’m on Windows 10, not sure it helps though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue is due to the fact I’m using `-debug` on the command line interface to GHC. I’ve been told `-debug` and `-p` are not compatible, hence the error.